# What does it mean "had never grown used to her money" in this sentence?

Tags: questions

I was reading "Cold Comfort Farm" in "Oxford Bookworm Library". And encounter the following sentence:

Like all people who have been disagreeably poor and had become deliciously rich, Mrs Smiling **had never grown used to her money**, and always took delight in thinking what a lot of it she had.

I did not understand the phrase "had never grown used to her money". Can you guys paraphrase it to help me understand this better, please?

Answer (score 1):

Read it as "never grown **accustomed** to it".

To be used to something, or accustomed to it, means that it feels natural, normal or commonplace to you. Evidently, Mrs Smiling had never grown accustomed to having money, and still enjoyed the 'novelty' of being rich.